# Transit via Uzbekistan from Germany to India

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, uzbekistan

Do I need a transit visa if I transit via Uzbekistan to India ?

I am travelling from Frankfurt to Mumbai via Tashkent.

Comment: Are we to infer your nationality is Indian?

Comment: Yes, My nationality is Indian.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have an air ticket to a 3rd country (India in your case). You can enter the country visa free for 5 days.

> From July 15th, 2018 a 5-day transit visa-free procedure will take effect for the citizens of 101 countries

India is on the list of 101 countries for visa free transit for it's citizens.

> Passengers need to provide an air-ticket to the third country and the carrier should inform the border authorities of Uzbekistan on passengers who are eligible for transit visa-free.

[Click here for the information](https://www.un.int/uzbekistan/news/republic-uzbekistan-introduces-e-visa-system-51-countries-and-5-day-transit-visa-free-procedure) from The Permanent Mission of the Republic of Uzbekistan to the United Nations.